# C: printf char* return weird last char

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I'm trying to understand why I've got a weird character after my `printf()`

```
char* extract_word()
{
    char* sentences = "hi! i'm a banana!";
    int starts = 4;
    int ends   = 12;
    int count;
    int nb_char = ends-starts+1;
    char* word = malloc(nb_char);
    printf("\n\n%d\n",ends-starts);
    for(count = starts; count < ends;count++)
    {
        word[count-starts] = sentences[count];
        printf("%c == \n",sentences[count]);
    }
    word[count-starts+1] = '\0';
    printf("\n\n%s",word);
    return word;
}
```

The `printf` returns:

> ```
> 8
>
> i ==
> ' ==
> m ==
>   ==
> a ==
>   ==
> b ==
> a ==
>
> i'm a bau
> ```

If I remove the `'\0'` I get something like:

> ```
>    'm a ba¨Á£´
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code

```
   word[count-starts+1] = '\0';
```

is [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) and basically that out-of-bound access invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should change your code to

```
   word[nb_char-1] = '\0';
```

because, you have allocated `nb_char` bytes and the last index would be `nb_char-1`.

That said, it's always required to check for the success of `malloc()` by checking the return against `NULL` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: Other options include `word[count-starts]='\0';` (this is more natural to me than `nb_char-1` given the use of variables in the code), or using `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Comment: @M.M I took the reference of `malloc(nb_char);`, but anyways, it's just mater of opinion. what's important is to keep within the bounds.

Comment: yeah. you're right. I Calculates to Avoid to overwrite the last character purpose in my loop, I counted wrong and. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `\0` printf has no way to know that the strings ends and will keep incrementing the pointer until it sees a null value and you take the risks of getting a segmentation fault.

For strings without a 0 at the end you can use `snprintf`

Also for what you are trying to achieve there's `memcpy` or `strncpy`

check the man pages for more details.

Comment: I can't using string.h or any other library except stdio.h to do that. I didn't know about `snprintf`. I'll read about it.